# Host wamp virtual host on port 81 and prevent typing port

Tags: php, asp.net, iis, wamp, private

**Hi**
I an using a VPS with Windows Server 2012 R2 hosting. I have to deploy web sites on both the IIS and WAMP.
IIS is running on port 80 (default), while I have changed the WAMP port to 81.
I can access my my sites as follows:
I access my IIS hosted sites as:
www.myIISSite.com
while I access my WAMP-hosted sites as:
www.myWAMPSite.com:81

My question is , how can I get rid of :81 after www.myWAMPSite.com while still using both the IIS and WAMP?
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd have to use your IIS server as a proxy before the apache server. So that the IIS serves _both_ domains (actually not domains, but hostnames), but only proxies the requests really meant for the apache server. A better alternative would be (since IIS is not exactly the best performing http server around), if you use a comman "frontend server". nginx is best suited for such task, and relay _both_ fat http servers through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Thanks for your response. As I asked the same question from my service provider, they told me to purchase an additional IP address for that purpose. I wonder why can't I hide port from the user, i.e. why does the user have to type in port number? While I was working on an open source project where I had to host both the Tomcat server files as well as PHP files, the tomcat server was running on port 8080 on Ubuntu 10 server and I didn't have to type in the port 8080 while opening the jsp pages.
Thanks a lot for your answer anyways.
**